# Google Maps no longer loads on iPad?

Tags: ipad, crash, google-maps

When I load the Google Maps app on my iPad, it simply quits before showing anything more than a grey screen, which I assume is a crash. Is there any way to fix this, or should I book an appointment at the genius bar?

If I do need to go to the apple store about it, how can I back up my data? I don't want to lose my files and Angry Birds progress if they need to wipe the iPad or something...

Answer (score 2):

It may well be that your iPad simply needs to be restarted in order to clean up the system memory.

#### Optional App Report

You can force the app to quit (which may result in losing information about your last trip or pin drop) and send a crash report to Apple by forcing it to quit in a specific way:

- Press and hold the power button on the top until "Slide to Power Off" appears
- Don't slide to power off.
- While "Slide..." is showing, press and hold the Home button.

This will force a "crash" to let Apple know exactly where the Maps app caused you to feel it needed a "force quit" and might help the engineers fix a bug if that's the cause.

#### Restarting the iPad

- Press and hold the power button on the top until "Slide to Power Off" appears.
- Slide to power off.
- Turn the iPad back on by pressing and holding the power button until the Apple logo appears.

The iPad 2 needs a power off less often due to the extra memory it has, but both devices occasionally need the user to force quit a problematic app as well as a clean reboot.

If these don't solve the problem then I'd go with the other suggestions here, but a clean restart may well fix things.

Comment: These are a nice selection of the steps from [general app troubleshooting steps](http://www.apple.com/support/ipad/assistant/application/)that can help when one app needs to be killed or the OS simply needs a restart to free up resources.

Comment: @bmike I re-edited the answer to better fit my intention: force quitting the app isn't likely to help, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds like a software issue.

Start by connecting to iTunes and doing a BACKUP by right clicking (Windows) or CTRL Click (Mac) on the iPad in the left hand panel of iTunes and choose the option to backup.

When backup is complete, click on restore which will wipe the contents of the device and set it back to factory settings. 
Test google maps immediately after the restore is complete to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely reach out to Apple for some hints on how to back things up in general and troubleshoot this if you aren't sure your settings are backed up. I've gotten many good tips from the staff - although sometimes a specific genius / AppleCare call is needed in odd ball problems where the normal steps don't help.

If you want, you can follow the [general app troubleshooting steps](http://www.apple.com/support/ipad/assistant/application/). Since it's a built in app - you can't report the problem in the app store or uninstall the app, but you can [restore the entire device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) which will keep all the settings intact.